# Parameterized query in SSIS Oracle data load

Tags: oracle, ssis, parameterized, attunity

I am learning to use SSIS to use between our Oracle ERP system and my SQL Server data warehouse

When loading transactional data (Inventory transactions) I have a unique auto increment integer Transaction_Id column that I would like to use in my SSIS data flow task

I understand that I would need to create a Parameter and fill this using a "Execute SQL Task", where I look up the latest transaction_id from my SQL Server table, then on to the "Data flow task" where I would use the parameter in a SQL Query.

My issue is that the Oracle connectors I am using "MS Oracle Source" From attunity does not allow me to add parameters to my query.

How would I go about getting my parameter value into my SQL query?

Comment: I have had similar issues with parameters.  You can use a variable and then use expressions to build out your query in that variable.  Then in your data flow pick execute query from variable.

Comment: That did the trick.